# How to build akka-protostuff-serialization?

Tags: build, akka, kryo, protostuff

I'm using akka (akka-2.2.1) through java and I'm not familiar with scala or sbt.
I need to change the serializer to one of the following.

https://github.com/romix/akka-protostuff-serialization

https://github.com/romix/akka-kryo-serialization

How to build these?

Comment: Can you be more specific? The official documentation is a good start http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/dev/building-akka.html

Comment: Have you read http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/serialization.html?